# pygtk import error from command window

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk

I've a GUI which is coded in pyGTK and which is used by clicking on a link in the Start Menu(Windows). It also opens a command window simultaneously through which the activity of the script is monitored. Since yesterday, the script has failed to startup. If I go to the particular folder in the command prompt and type "Xero_GUI.py", it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Cisco_Building_systems\ULTA Docking\Docking_GUI.py",
    line 1, in <module>
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

But this same script works fine when run like:

```
python Xero_GUI.py
```

Any help to why this is happening would be really helpful.

Comment: There is no DOS. Forget about DOS. DOS is long gone (at least in terms of Windows). Changed all occurrences of DOS to command :-)

Comment: can you dump sys.path just before the import (import sys, print sys.path).

Comment: @Marco - this is the sys.path. The GUI script is in the first path - ['C:\\Program Files\\XB\\xb\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk' , 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']